# Is it a good or bad idea to maintain references to Assembly objects to avoid unnecessary calls of Assembly.LoadFrom?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, assembly-loading

In a plugin system I instantiate objects and call methods of those objects based on some incoming requests which have some identifier (simply a string). With the help of a configuration this identifier determines which assembly to load, which class in this assembly to instantiate and which method to call. The assemblies are loaded into a separate AppDomain. This happens in a proxy class which is created like so:

```
secondDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase,
    typeof(SecondDomainProxy).FullName) as SecondDamainProxy;
```

In the class SecondDomainProxy I load the assembly which is related to the `identifier` mentioned above:

```
string assemblyFileName = GetAssemblyFileNameFromConfig(identifier);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFileName);
// Instantiate and run something in assembly
```

Question: Does it make sense to hold a reference to this Assembly object once the assembly has been loaded? For instance with a Dictionary...

```
Dictionary<string, Assembly> _assemblyDict;
```

... and by changing the code above to:

```
Assembly assembly;
if (!_assemblyDict.TryGetValue(identifier, out assembly))
{
    string assemblyFileName = GetAssemblyFileNameFromConfig(identifier);
    assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFileName);
    _assemblyDict[identifier] = assembly;
}
// Instantiate and run something in assembly
```

I am aware that the assembly is loaded after the first call of Assembly.LoadFrom forever until the AppDomain is unloaded. (The second AppDomain lives as long as the main application in my case.) So does that mean that a second call to Assembly.LoadFrom is cheap, as cheap or almost as cheap as the dictionary lookup? Or does it have drawbacks NOT to call assembly.LoadFrom and to use the saved reference instead?

(My feeling is that it doesn't really matter unless I have high performance requirements which I don't have (one request every 15 seconds roughly). But I could be wrong.)

Thank you for feedback in advance!

**Edit:**

`Assembly` is a "normal" .NET class. If I don't have any references to an instance of this class it gets garbage collected, I think. But the assembly itself keeps still loaded. So `Assembly.LoadFrom` needs at least to create a new instance of the Assembly class, although at the second time this instance creation might be based on the already loaded assembly.

I'd like to add the question: Does creating an assembly object for a given assembly require some heavy reflection and is therefore always expensive, no matter if the assembly is loaded or not?

Comment: @Hans: Could you take a look at my Edit I just appended to the question? Does it change your statement? Does every loaded assembly have a static `Assembly` object assigned which is simply returned by `LoadFrom` instead of creating a new instance?

Comment: If you are worried about performance - measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

Once loaded into an AppDomain, the assembly can accessed by using the GetAssemblies() method of the underlying AppDomain object that returns any loaded/available Assembly, s: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx

The only way to unload one or more Assemblies is to unload the AppDomain, by using static Unload() method of the same class.